# Python 3.6 - How to pass file names into unique variables

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'd like to assign unique variable name with each file from a directory. I have no idea how this can be done. I'm new to python, so I'm sorry is the code is scruffy.

```
def DataFinder(path, extension):
    import os
    count = 0
    extensions = ['.txt','.csv','.xls','xlsm','xlsx']
    allfiles = []

    if not extension in extensions:
        print('Can\'t read data from this file type.\n','Allowed file types are\n',str(extensions))
    else:
        #loop through the files
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                #check if the file ends with the extension
                if file.endswith(extension):
                    count+=1
                    print(str(count)+': '+file)
                    allfiles.append(file)

        if count==0:
            print('There are no files with',extension,'extension in this folder.')
    return allfiles
```

How this code be modified to assign variable name like **df_number.of.file** with each iteration as a string?

Thanks

My ultimate goal is to have set of DataFrame objects for each file under unique variable name without a need to create those variables manually.

The suggested duplicate did not answer my question, neither worked for me.

```
allfiles = {}
        #filter through required data extensions
        if not extension in extensions:
            print('Can\'t read data from this file type.\n','Allowed file types are\n',str(extensions))
        else:
            #loop through the files
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                for file in files:
                    #check if the file ends with the extension
                    if file.endswith(extension):
                        #raise counter
                        count+=1
                        print(str(count)+': '+file)
                        allfiles.update({'df'+str(count) : path+file})
```

After adjusting the code as suggested my output was a dictionary:

{'df1': 'C:/Users/Bartek/Downloads/First.csv', 'df2': 'C:/Users/Bartek/Downloads/Second.csv', 'df3': 'C:/Users/Bartek/Downloads/Third.csv'}

I achieved similar thing previously using list:

['df_1First.csv', 'df_2Second.csv', 'df_3Third.csv']

But my exact question is how to achieve this:

for each object in dict:
-create a variable with consecutive object number

so this variable(s) can be passed as data argument to pandas.DataFrame()

I know this is very bad idea (http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html), therefore can you please show me proper way using dict?

Many thanks

Comment: Don't do it--setting the name of a value based on the value is bad programming practice. Instead, use a dictionary, where the desired name is the key.

Comment: @RoryDaulton thank you. How can I ask the right question to find an answer about using dictionary for this purpose please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to modify this section of the code to accomplish what you desire. Instead of printing out the number of files. use `count` to create new unique filenames.

```
if file.endswith(extension):
  count+=1
  newfile = ('df_' + str(count) + file)
  allfiles.append(newfile)
```

`count` would be unique for each different file extension. You should be able to find the newly created file names in `allfiles`.

EDIT to use a **dictionary** (thanks Rory): I would suggest an alternative route. create a dictionary and use the file name as the key.

```
allfilesdict = {}
...
if file.endswith(extension):
  count+=1
  newfile = ('df_' + str(count) + file)
  allfilesdict[file] = newfile
```

then remember to return the `allfilesdict` if you are going to use it somewhere outside of your function.

Comment: Thank you OLIVER.KOO. I'm sorry if I confused things a bit here. I'm calling the function from this code:


    path = input('What is the folder path?\n')
    ext = input('What is the file extension? (i.e. .xls)\n')

    import DataProject as dp
    p = dp.FileHandler.DataFinder(path,ext)
    print(p)

Ideally I wanted to return unique variables with strings for each file found that can be passed to pd.read_excel, read_csv etc.

Comment: are you trying to create `df_numberOfFiles` string for each file, does the extension matter? are you concatenating  `df_numberOfFiles`  with the file name? can you give a simple example?

Comment: I think I wanted to approach it the bad way as explained by Rory.

Comment: Rory suggested using a `dictionary` which I included in the edit. modify your `DataFinder` function to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify first script like these.

from time import gmtime, strftime

import os

def DataFinder(path, extension):

```
count = 0
extensions = ['.txt','.csv','.xls','xlsm','xlsx']
allfiles = []

if not extension in extensions:
    print('Can\'t read data from this file type.\n','Allowed file types are\n',str(extensions))
else:
    #loop through the files
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            #check if the file ends with the extension
            if file.endswith(extension):
                count+=1
                #taking date and time
                date_time=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                #now to get file name we are splite with (.)dot so in list we get first (i.e.file_name[0]) file name and (i.e.file_name[1]) as extension.
                file_name=file.split('.')
                allfiles.append(file_name[0]+date_time+'.'+file_name[1])

    if count==0:
        print('There are no files with',extension,'extension in this folder.')
return allfiles
```

print DataFinder('/home/user/tmp/test','.csv')